# Window Dimensions different depending on Orientation

Tags: javascript, iphone, web-applications

So i'm making a Web App that is going to run from the homescreen in iphone, using the metatags:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
```

I have this javascript code to handle orientation change:

```
var orientationChange = function(e){
    if(typeof mainContainer === 'undefined'){
        mainContainer = document.querySelector('.main-container');
    }
    alert(window.innerWidth + ' * ' + window.innerHeight);
};

window.addEventListener('orientationchange', orientationChange, false);
window.addEventListener('load', orientationChange, false);
```

when the device is in portrait mode, i get

```
320(w) * 460(h)
```

and when the device is in landscape mode i get

```
480(w) * 300(h)
```

Why does this happen?
Is there a way to guarantee that i will get a consistent result?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS if you only want change your profile depending on a specific resolution:

```
 @media (min-width: 320px) { look one way... }
 @media (min-width: 240px) { look another way... }
```

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't see how that answers my questions